# Can I configure a Plan Trigger to run a dynamic branch daily?

Tags: bamboo

## Problem

Bamboo runs daily integration tests on integration environment. When the *bamboo branch* is different to *integration test environment* these tests tend to fail partially. (any new tests in newer branch fail)

### What I'm trying to do to solve this?

1. Use bamboo Command to get the current branch deployed on integration
2. Use that value somehow to tell bamboo to trigger that specific branch on the current run

Any idea on how I tell bamboo to run the plan on the specified branch?

Answer (score 1):

You can use REST call to add build into queue,

```
/queue/{projectKey}-{buildKey}?stage&executeAllStages&customRevision
```

https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo/REST/5.13.1/#d2e413

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well. Wish bamboo had a way to pick the branch dynamically